# Holding non-immigrant J1 visa and dutch dependent visa simultaneously

Tags: netherlands, schengen, j-visa, dependent-visa

I am non-US and non-EU national employed in USA with a non-immigrant J1 visa. My spouse is a Netherlands resident and that's why I am eligible for getting a dutch dependent visa. After getting the visa, I have to register in Netherlands as a resident. But can I hold both visa simultaneously i.e. remain employed in US with J1 visa and use the dutch dependent visa to show as a resident in Netherlands?

Comment: Of course you can, why not? Just be careful of the tax implications of registering as a resident in the NL when you actually reside in the US.  Also, if you hold a dependent visa but aren't actually residing in the Netherlands, is it really necessary to register? I would think it isn't, that you only need to register if you're living there.  Maybe you can get a regular Schengen visa for the time when you're living in the US and visiting your wife occasionally.

Comment: @phoog registering as soon as possible would allow OP to get permanent residency (and then citizenship) faster.

Comment: @phoog also it should be noted that residency and tax residency are two different things. So OP won't necessarily be hurt by any tax implications.

Comment: @JonathanReez they're not *necessarily* the same, but, for example, in Italy as I understand it, if you're registered as a resident then you're liable for.income tax regardless of your physical presence.  It's possible, indeed likely, that the same is true in the Netherlands.  There's also as I understand a requirement to deregister when you move out of the Netherlands, which implies it's at least improper to register when you don't live there.